# How to get tab completion work properly in telnet-mode

Tags: shell

I'm trying to get command and file tab completion to work in telnet-mode.

For that, I did  bind the <kbd>TAB</kbd> key to `completion-at-point` in `telnet-mode-map`.  The function is called as expected but it does not work properly (not providing the completion list and printing erratically).

The `completion-at-point` works fine `shell-mode` for instance.
Is it possible to get it working properly under telnet-mode?

Comment: [`telnet.el`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/net/telnet.el) does not support completion. But you can abbreviate telnet commands. A unique start string of the command is sufficient to call the command.

Comment: @Tobias do you think it would be possible to add telnet completion support to telnet.el?  Is there something that would prevent it?

Comment: Are you https://github.com/PRouleau ? Interested in setting up a Git repo?

Comment: Note, that is me: https://github.com/TobiasZawada/  I am not as experienced as Drew or MilkyPostMan, but I have at least some experience in setting up packages. So I could help you. But, I cannot maintain packages that I am not really using. Pityingly, the original author of telnet William F. Schelter passed away. But, if we want to get completion for telnet working we need some help from the maintainers (i.e., pityingly, `emacs-devel@gnu.org`) to fix some issues in `telnet.el`.

Comment: Thanks @Tobias, I'll look into it later, and will try to get it going in a clone of the file first.  I don't have time now but will try later when I get time.  I have to use telnet sometimes for local testing of embedded systems where telnet is activated for engineering testing only and where ssh is not available.

Answer (score 1):

`telnet-mode` is not prepared for completion.
The following code shows how you can add completion support with the help of `pcomplete`.

I don't use `telnet`. So the code is certainly broken.
Use the code just as a general direction of how you can add completion.
I think you will need some support from the maintainer of `telnet.el` to fix the little bugs in the code.

Note, that only some example telnet commands are implemented.
You need to complete the set of commands `pcomplete/telnet-mode/COMMAND` yourself.

```el
(require 'telnet)
(require 'pcomplete)

;; Somehow `telnet-send-input' messes up the promopt.
;; Pressing RET repeately causes multiple prompts on one line.
;; With multiple prompts on one line `pcomplete' does no longer recognize commands.
;; The following fixes that problem for `pcomplete'
;; but it certainly breaks something in `telnet'.
;; That needs to be cleared with the maintainer of the package.
(advice-add 'telnet-send-input :override #'comint-send-input)

(defconst telnetTZA-commands
  '("auth"
    "close"
    "display"
    "encrypt"
    "environ"
    "logout"
    "mode"
    "open"
    "quit"
    "send"
    "set"
    "unset"
    "slc"
    "toggle"
    "z"
    "!"
    "?"
    )
  "List of telnet commands according to the Man page of telnet.")

(defun telnetTZA-pcomplete-command ()
  "Complete telnet command."
  (pcomplete-here
   telnetTZA-commands))

(defun telnetTZA-pcomplete-setup ()
  "Setup pcomplete for `telnet-mode'."
  (setq-local pcomplete-command-completion-function #'telnetTZA-pcomplete-command)
  (local-set-key [tab] #'completion-at-point)
  (pcomplete-comint-setup 'comint-dynamic-complete-functions))

(add-hook 'telnet-mode-hook #'telnetTZA-pcomplete-setup)

;; `comint-run-thing-process' is just a helper. We move its definition behind the essential stuff.
(declare-function #'comint-run-thing-process load-file-name)

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Completion of commands in `telnet-mode':

(defun pcomplete/telnet-mode/auth ()
  "Complete args of \"auth\" command in `telnet-mode'."
  ;; first argument
  (pcomplete-here
   '("disable" "enable" "status"))
  ;; second argument
  (pcomplete-here
   (pcase (pcomplete-arg 1)
     ("disable"
      (telnetTZA-completion-from-help "disable ?"))
     ("enable"
      (telnetTZA-completion-from-help "enable ?")))))

(defun pcomplete/telnet-mode/environ ()
  "Complete args of \"environ\" command in `telnet-mode'."
  ;; first arg
  (pcomplete-here
   '("define" "undefine" "export" "unexport" "send" "list" "?"))
  ;; second arg
  (pcomplete-here
   (when (member (pcomplete-arg 1) '("undefine" "export" "unexport" "send"))
     (telnetTZA-completion-from-help "environ list"))))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; Helpers:

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; `comint-run-thing-process' is stolen from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46631920/silently-send-command-to-comint-without-printing-prompt.
;; There is also needed some work here.
(defun comint-run-thing-process (process command)
  "Send COMMAND to PROCESS."
  (let ((output-buffer " *Comint Redirect Work Buffer*"))
    (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create output-buffer)
      (erase-buffer)
      (comint-redirect-send-command-to-process command
                                               output-buffer process nil t)
      ;; Wait for the process to complete
      (set-buffer (process-buffer process))
      (while (and (null comint-redirect-completed)
                  (accept-process-output process)))
      ;; Collect the output
      (set-buffer output-buffer)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      ;; Skip past the command, if it was echoed
      (and (looking-at command)
           (forward-line))
      ;; Grab the rest of the buffer
      (buffer-substring-no-properties (point) (- (point-max) 1)))))

(defun telnetTZA-completion-from-help (command)
  "Run COMMAND in telnet buffer and collect first word for each line."
  (let* ((output (comint-run-thing-process (get-buffer-process (current-buffer)) command))
     (lines (split-string output "\n"))
     (words (seq-remove
         #'string-empty-p
         (mapcar
          (lambda (str)
            (setq str (string-trim-left str))
            (string-trim-right str "[[:space:]].*"))
          lines))))
    words))
```